# How to covert timezone like 'UTC+5.5' to supported format?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm using one API which returns time zone in format like "UTC+5.5" or "UTC+4". As i'm building application on Laravel, i can't figure out how to change it to supported php timezones.
[image]

Currently i using this code to fetch it.

```
<?php
$offset = 'UTC+5.5';
$offset = substr($offset,3);
// Calculate seconds from offset
list($hours, $minutes) = explode('.', $offset);
$seconds = $hours * 60 * 60 + ($minutes*60*0.1) * 60;
// Get timezone name from seconds
$tz = timezone_name_from_abbr('', $seconds, 1);
// Workaround for bug #44780
if($tz === false) $tz = timezone_name_from_abbr('', $seconds, 0);


echo $tz;
```

Comment: Can you provide some code examples of what you have tried so far?

Comment: You check Carbon php library, it has all you need for datetime formatting

Comment: @thisiskelvin. I Added image to show what i get as response for timezone. I want to convert it to php supported timezones. https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: There is no 1:1 relation between these named timezones, and a specific UTC offset. Randomly picking one that matches the offset makes rather little sense, I think - and could probably even be error prone, if DST comes into play. What is the actual purpose of what you are trying to do here - do you want a “nice looking” timezone name that you can display to the user, or is this about actually working with the timestamp values you got from that API in some way, so that you want to convert them into a proper DateTime instance or something like that?

Comment: @04FS Yes. I need a proper DateTime Instance.

Comment: Then I’d create a DateTimeZone instance first. The constructor does not only take timezone names, but also offsets in the form `+0200`. Parsing `UTC+5.5` and creating the corresponding offset value in that format should be relatively easy.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$dt = Carbon::parse($request->time)->timezone('America/Los_Angeles');
```